# How to create a dense matrix from uint[,] array

Tags: math.net

I am trying to create a DenseMatrix in MathDotNet from a uint array with two dimensions.

```
uint[10,10] = myarray;
Matrix<ushort> newarray = Matrix<ushort>.Build.DenseOfArray(myarray);
```

Mathdotnet complains about this beeing not implemented yet. Only floating point type matrices are implemented. What I would like to do is this:

```
uint[10,10] = myarray;
Matrix<double> newarray = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(myarray);
```

But this fails, because myarray is of a different type than the Matrix.
Is there a way of implicitly converting my uint array to double to solve this problem?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Do you want newarray to use integer arithmetic  or floating point arithmetic in subsequent calculations?

Comment: I would like to use floating point arithmetic. That is the reason for the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think casting can work in this case, but there is a mechanism to contruct a matrix from an arbitrary indexable source:

```
Matrix<double> newarray = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(
    myarray.GetLength(0), myarray.GetLength(1), (i,j) => myarray[i,j]);
```